# PayPal Error: 13122 "This transaction cannot be completed because it violates the PayPal User Agreement."

Tags: api, paypal

One of our users is getting an error when they attempt to make a purchase and I'm trying to identify why this is occurring.

The message returned from PayPal is:

```
<Errors xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<ShortMessage>Transaction refused</ShortMessage>
<LongMessage>This transaction cannot be completed because it violates the PayPal User Agreement.</LongMessage>
<ErrorCode>13122</ErrorCode>
<SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
</Errors>
```

This product is working for other users, just not him.

Obviously it's violating the User Agreement but I'd like to identify why.

*UPDATE*

The users that are affected by it seem to all have one or more of the following: a non-UK email address, a non-UK PayPal account or a non-UK payment source.

We've not had a resolution yet, but have directed several users to contact PayPal directly. The feedback we've had is as follows:

"I tried with another paypal account, that failed too, despite being able to use both PayPal accounts to pay for other services."

"PayPal are aware of the error message, but they simply cannot explain why it's happening. After an hour on the phone with them today, they seem incapable of tracing the reason for this error."

Needless to say we've got some very frustrated users.

Comment: I'd rather send a mail to paypal support. If something on the userside is wrong with Paypals UA, you won't get any reasons for the error because of privacy.

Comment: We've logged a support call, unfortunately they've not responded. I'll try them again.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem... Title of our item we were selling was:

```
Inc. Special Offer: <<Famous author>> eBook for only 10.00$
```

When we changed the title to something more descriptive, everything was OK

Answer (score 1):

Did you open a ticket with MTS or call the Business Support line? If you did open a ticket can you please give me the ticket number? I'll take a look at it.

It may be something that you need to address with Business Support though.

Comment: I'll take a look at the ticket and reply to it for you.

Comment: Update - We've not had a resolution yet, but have directed several users to PayPal. The feedback we've had is as follows: <Br />

Comment: The last update I've had from PayPal is:

The transaction wasn't a violation of the PayPal user agreement. It's an issue with the buyer's funding source being declined by our risk model and for some reason this API error was triggered. I'm not sure if it is the correct error to be returned for a decline like this. The error mapping seems a little off. I'm going to reach out to the Express Checkout team to find out more and if we can get the error messaging changed for a decline like this.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the value in "PaymentDetailsItem - Name" was *one* part of the problem. We didn't have any special characters (or so I thought) in there, just "product name: person name". When I spoke to PayPal support their response is as follows:

"I have checked it, it's a combination of many things that we cannot disclose.
However removing the ":" before the name PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME should work.

Can you send PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME=xxxx USER NAME
Instead of PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME=xxxx : USER NAME"

Once I had removed the ":" from that field, it started working again...bizarre!

This error still gets triggered with non-UK PayPal accounts but happens less frequently now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error coming back for one of our customers and I had the same issue as @knagode with my product name.

For some reason "Dark Havana" in the product name set this off and produced this error. If I ever hear back from Paypal on why this phrase is not acceptable, I will circle back and edit this response.

Comment: Hi - When I spoke to them last they wouldn't tell me why the words triggered the block as it would be a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

For any others investigating this issue please be aware that PayPal has filters in place that looks for globally specific geographic terms. If any terms used in the product description trigger the filters, the transaction could be refused. In our case, we are online rug retailer with many of our products ranging across the traditional rug spectrum. We found that any rug with the term "Persia" in the title were being refused due to economic sanctions against nation states associated with that term.

The filters are not geographic only and other controversial terms could also trigger the filters to refuse the transaction. In one instance, we had a rug with "Confederate" in the product description that also triggered the filters.